# Navigating between named routes for same Path/URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have two routes but problem is that they both share same Path/url, like this

router.js-->

```
{
path: '/',
name: 'getin',
components: {
  default: Getin,
  AppFooter
}
},    
{
path:"/",
name: landing
components: {
  default: landing
  AppNav
}
},
```

index.html-->

```
    <router-view name="AppNav"></router-view>
    <div class=" jumbo-container">
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
    </div>
    <router-view name="AppFooter"></router-view>
```

as it might seems so, `Getin` is the state when you put your credentials and landing loads as soon as you are authorized.

now when i am authorizing in `Getin` Component, and i execute`this.$router.push({name:'landing'})`, nothing happens, all i want to do is keep same Path/URL and have different views, i could put them in a single component but that does not sound alright to me, given their significance is a lot different.

Answer (score 0):

By your own admission: "their significance is a lot different.". So they should be separate paths. Name one "/getin" and one "/landing", and push to /landing if the auth in /getin is successful. Also add a beforeEnter hook so that you can't get to /landing directly, but only through /getin

Comment: but thing is I am not using any URL in my app, there is only one url , i just want to use named routes. it is SPA.

Comment: Are you using VueRouter? SPAs can have more than one route still. If you use named routes, you need different routes. Otherwise, you can use the `is` tag to switch the component

Comment: yes I am using vuerouter but how do it go about it with 'is' tag, i have to push to named route of same Path

Comment: You cannot have two paths that go to the same place, and just change the name. You need to have two routes!

Comment: Thanks, i understand it better now, there is no need for it, it was a flaw in my app. But to think of it, it should be possible to do it. Angular 1 ui.router provided function to operate only on named routes, paths were not relevant there. Just my opinion.

Comment: SPA just means a single page, not a single route. As far as the browser is concerned, it doesn't navigate to a new page.